# eclipse scanner filenotfoundexception when I use a string as the file name

Tags: java, eclipse

I have used notepad my entire time as a CS student.  In notepad the following works fine

```
class someclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("some.txt"));
    }
}
```

In netbeans I have to use the actual full-path enclosed in "", and put the code in a try catch as well.

In eclipse however, nothing seams to work.  If I use the the full path name in "" it gives me an escape sequence error.  If I just use the code listed above, with a try catch, with a .close(), I still I get filenotfound....please advise.

ps, for my own edification why do I not have to close or use try catch in notepad?

Comment: And where is your "some.txt" located?

Comment: Try printing out the working directory Java is using. It may not be where you expect. `System.getProperty("user.dir")`

Answer (score 1):

> why do I not have to close or use try catch in notepad?

Theoretically, you don't need to do that in IDEs either, but IDEs go further than the compiler and warn you about non closed resources etc; such warnings can become errors if your IDE is configured as such. As to `try`/`catch` this looks strange since you declare your `main` to throw `Exception`.

But IDEs are right on one point here: when you open a `Closeable` resource, you should `.close()` it when done with it.

> If I use the the full path name in "" it gives me an escape sequence error

Wild guess: you use Windows, and you paste a path such as `C:\myfile.txt` directly between the two quotes. This is indeed a malformed string: backslashes in Java strings need to be doubled.

> I have to use the actual full-path enclosed in ""

Which means the process' working directory is not where you think it is. Generally, in IDEs, the working directory is the project root. Either move your file to this working directory or use the full path.

Comment: when you say project root do you mean \workspace\project\mytxt or \project\mytext.   do I need to lead with a '\'.

Comment: Maybe... I don't use Eclipse nor NetBeans, I use IDEA. But that sounds reasonable enough.

Answer (score 0):

> In notepad the following works just fine

Think about how you run your code. I might be making assumptions, but I believe it goes something like this.

```
javac -cp . Someclass.java
java SomeClass
```

And your directory structure looks something like this.

**please note that /someTestproject is a directory I am making up for this example*

```
/someTestProject
/someTestProject/Someclass.java
/someTestProject/Someclass.class
/someTestProject/some.txt
```

When your application runs it looks for resources relative to its execution path. In the case where you're running from the command line it looks for some.txt relative to the directory you're in (in this case /someTestProject).

However, in the IDE world things are not so simple. Your source folder is never your build & run folder. So if you have some.txt in your source folder in your project it most likely will not be found when it runs. The below illustrates how most IDE work.

```
/workspace/project/src
/workspace/project/class
```

Where ../src is where all your java files reside and /class is where all your compiled classes reside.

There are a few ways around this issue, but they differ depending on which IDE you're using. I myself have not used netbeans in a while, but I believe you can locate your execution directory in the project settings. In eclipse you can simply drag the file into your project, but outside the src folder.

> In netbeans I have to use the actual full-path enclosed in "", and put
>   the code in a try catch as well.

When you open your file some.txt the resource is located at runtime. The Scanner class declares that it throws a FileNotFoundException in case it can't locate the file. You should either handle this in a try/catch to gracefully bow out or declare that your main throws a FileNotFoundException which will cause your program to crash when it occurs.

> In eclipse however, nothing seams to work. If I use the the full path
>   name in "" it gives me an escape sequence error...

I'm going to guess that you're using windows. Remember, that in Java strings a backslash \ is an escape character. Think about \n (newline) \t (tab) or how to include quotes in a string "\"Hello\", said sam.

If you try the following it will fail.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:\Users\you\Desktop\some.txt"));
```

On windows you should be using

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\you\\Desktop\\some.txt"));
```

Remember that to include backslash in your string you must use two backslashes.

> for my own edification why do I not have to close or use try catch in
>   notepad?

Since your exception is thrown in main it doesn't need to be declared or wrapped in a try/catch. However, IDE try to enforce good programming practice. I believe most IDE have a setting to allow you to control how much your IDE complains at your programming practice.